# how to add close button in Appended Items?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, onclick, append

I work on a project where I use the Localstorage function along with clone and it works fine

but the problem how to add number increment in .count class like I click on **save1 save2 save3** then total number count shown like `<div class='count'>3</div>`

Here is Demo of my code [JsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pikitemplates/sjb51fkc/99/)

here is my code below where I try to add .count system along with all append elements but I am not able to add

```js
$('.item-all .item-save').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('productad')
  window.localStorage.setItem('test' + this.dataset.id, $(this).hasClass('productad'));
});
$('.item-all .item-save').each(function() {
  var id = 'test' + this.dataset.id;
  if (localStorage.getItem(id) && localStorage.getItem(id) == "true") {
    $(this).addClass('productad');
    $(this).clone().appendTo('.item-append');
  }
});
$(".item-all .item-save").click(function() {
  var existing = $(".item-append [data-id=" + $(this).data("id") + "]");
  if (existing.length > 0)
    existing.remove();
  else
    $(this).clone().appendTo('.item-append');
});
$(".close").click(function() {
localStorage.removeItem("'test' + this.dataset.id"), $(this).removeClass('productad');
  
});
```

```css
.item-save {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    width:80px;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    background: #a5a5a5;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.item-all{display:flex}
.productad{background:red;color:#eee}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='item-all'>
<div class='item-save' data-id='123'>
Save1
</div>
<div class='item-save' data-id='124'>
Save2
</div>
<div class='item-save' data-id='125'>
Save3
</div>
<div class='item-save' data-id='126'>
save4
</div>
</div>
<hr/>
<div class='item-append'>
<div class='count'>3</div>
</div>
```

The close buttons look like this I need [image: DEMO of Close Buttons I tried to create]

Any kind of help or suggestions is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check you can create a function and there create a div element and append the cloned item and append a close button created from the code, then you can reuse that function to create elements from any method, you just need to pass the selected object and in the "close" method you can use the function "parent" to select the "div" parent element and get the attribute id from there, like the code below.

```js
function createItem(item){
    var elemId = item.data("id");
    var clonedItem = item.clone();
    var newItem = $(`<div data-id="${elemId}"></div>`);
    newItem.append(clonedItem);
    newItem.append(`<button class='close'>Close</button>`)
    newItem.appendTo('.item-append');
}

function countSaveItems(){
    $('.count').html($(".item-append div.item-save[data-id]").length);
}


$('.item-all .item-save').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('productad')
  window.localStorage.setItem('test_' + this.dataset.id, $(this).hasClass('productad'));
});
$('.item-all .item-save').each(function() {
  var id = 'test_' + $(this).data("id"); //
  if (localStorage.getItem(id) && localStorage.getItem(id) == "true") {
    $(this).addClass('productad');
    createItem($(this));
    countSaveItems();
  }
});
$(".item-all .item-save").click(function() {
  var elemId = $(this).data("id");
  var existing = $(`.item-append div[data-id="${elemId}"]`);
  if (existing.length > 0){
    existing.remove();
  }else{
    createItem($(this));
  }
  countSaveItems();
});

$(".item-append").on("click", ".close", function() {
    var id = $(this).parent().data("id");
    localStorage.removeItem(`test_${id}`);
  $(`.item-save[data-id='${id}']`).removeClass('productad');
    $(this).parent().remove();
  countSaveItems();
  
} );
```

```css
.item-save {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    width:80px;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    background: #a5a5a5;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.item-all{display:flex}
.productad{background:red;color:#eee}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='item-all'>
<div class='item-save' data-id='123'>
Save1
</div>
<div class='item-save' data-id='124'>
Save2
</div>
<div class='item-save' data-id='125'>
Save3
</div>
<div class='item-save' data-id='126'>
save4
</div>
</div>
<hr/>
<div class='item-append'>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time to answer but the problem is close button not working I update your code in jsFiddle please check [Js Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pikitemplates/sjb51fkc/109/) I hope this will resolve i don't know why close button not working

Comment: Oh, sorry is the close selector in that case we need to use on to trigger the event by selecting the existing element, I updated the answer, check now and let me know

Comment: Sorry it didn't work when I click on the close button it closes but not from local storage when I refresh the browser the close button appears again

Comment: I commented the local storage code, but why you want to store in local storage

Comment: please check the jsFiddle localsotrage close button not working?

its project I need to store in locastorage please help me to solve the issue

Comment: I added the changes to remove local storage items in the close button, in the close button I added the remove from local storage the item, also you can create a function to remove and add items into local storage because looks like you gonna reuse that code in your project.

Comment: Thanks for your precious time sir, I am going to mark the question as Solve tick, but before this have a last little bit request help - how to add number increment in **.count** class like I click on **save1 save2 save3** then total number count showed like `<div class='count'>3</div>`
Please can you guide me to add number increment `(0 - n) n - means up to so on`
 Above Question is Updated ❤️

Comment: one way is you can use the length with jquery like this $('.count').length and increment the value +1

Comment: That's great but it difficult for  beginner can you update the Answer sir ❤️

Comment: I added the function to the answer, if you check I added a function countSaveItems, there use a selector to referred to all inserted items and then do a length method

Comment: It works when we click on `save1 save2 save3` increment work but when we again click on `save1 save2 save3` the increment decrease but it freezes at **"1"** there is no 0 value displayed check this [jsFiddle Please](https://jsfiddle.net/pikitemplates/sjb51fkc/166/) I hope I get a solution ❤️

Comment: I added the fix to the js code

Comment: You're hero sir i marked question solve if you don't mind can we friends please any social media account you have

Comment: Please waiting for your answer yes or no sir

Comment: yes, you can contact me via LinkedIn https://www.linkedin.com/in/josecore/?locale=en_US just give me your full name to accept your request

Comment: Thanks very much, Manu Dhiman ❤️ Please check I tried to send to connect request I think due privacy , please confirm request received [https://www.linkedin.com/in/dev-manu-pikitemplates](https://www.linkedin.com/in/dev-manu-pikitemplates/)